# Is there a general notion of entropy for the states of a C*algebra?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

I've seen some definition of the relative entropy between two states of a C*algebra. However this definitions work only for finite dimensional C*algebras and I don't know if there is a correspondent notion for only one state.

Comment: The short answer is: No. Entropy is a relative thing ...

Comment: Thank you. I think entropy is not necessarilly relative. It is a measure of uncertainty of a set of phenomena and, in that sense, it is perfectly possible there to be a definition of entropy for a single state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different definitions of entropy associated with operator algebras. It would be good if you knew which one you were referring to. Do you have a reference? I expect you're talking about the generalization of Kullback-Leibler relative entropy to matrix algebras.

There's a perfectly good definition of entropy for density matrices (positive self-adjoint trace 1 matrices); this is called [von Neumann entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy), and although I haven't thought about it I think you should be able to extend it to a definition of entropy for self-adjoint trace 1 operators for II$_1$ factors in von Neumann algebras in the same way that you can extend Shannon entropy to continuous distributions by using differential entropy. In fact, I'd be surprised if that hasn't already been done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May be it is possible to generalize the Kullback-Leibler relative entropy to arbitrary states.

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered the work of H. Araki who used Tomita-Takesaki theory to generalize relative entropy between two states to arbitrary Von Neumann Algebras.

Comment: Look into Quantum entropy and its use by Ohya and Petz, https://link.springer.com/book/9783540208068. There Entropy is defined in terms of relative entropy, and relative entropy is showed to be the unique functional with certain intuitive properties we expect from relative information